# A consistent way to import files such that the import statement is valid for normal python scripts and also within packages

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm working on a package that has the following directory structure:

```
setup.py
README.md
src/
    __init__.py
    file.py
    subpackage/
        ...
tests/
    ...
```

I want to import `file.py` in `__init__.py`

This import statement works when I directly run `__init__.py`:

```
import file
.
.
.
object = file.class()
```

But it fails when I install the package using pip by using `python -m pip install .` (the `.` refers to the root package directory) and call `__init__.py` using an entry point defined in `setup.py`

I get the following error for the same import statement:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file'
```

I observed that the import succeeds in the entry script if I do:

```
from . import file
```

But it fails when I run **init**.py the regular way with this error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

For reference, here's the entry script defined in `setup.py`:

```
entry_points={
'gui_scripts': [
'runpack =packagename.__init__:main',
],
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: it looks like everything is relative to `setup.py`.......

Comment: @D.L can you please expand on that? Do you mean everything is relative to setup.py when the entry script is used?

Comment: Your file directory structure does not seem correct. First thing, I would recommend you to rename the `src` directory to `packagename` (or something like that). Then only ever use absolute imports, which means that imports of your own project should start with `packagename` (for example `import packagename` or `from packagename import file`). Then your entry point should probably be `runpack=packagename:main`, the `__init__` is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

First, your file directory structure does not seem correct. I would recommend you to rename the `src` directory to `packagename` (or something like that), which will be your "top-level importable package".

I also recommend to only ever use absolute imports, which means that all imports should start from the top-level importable packages. So to import from your own project the import statements should start from `packagename`. For example `import packagename.file` or `from packagename import file`.

It seems to me like your entry point should be `runpack=packagename:main`, the `__init__` is not needed here.

I would also add a `packagename/__main__.py` file with a content similar to this:

```py
import packagename

def my_main():
    return packagename.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_main()
```

Finally you could run your code as either `python -m packagename` or `runpack` but you definitely should not run your code as `python packagename/__init__.py` or `python packagename/__main__.py`.